# Input values aren't being stored in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a simple login form. I'm not able to store user input values at the back-end. Here's the full code for your reference:

#### dp.php

```
<?php
    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'list') or trigger_error(mysqli_error());
    $first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
    $last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email_id'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO login_list (first_name, last_name, email,password) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email','$password')";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($dbc));
    echo 'login created';
    mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Comment: Could you post HTML code of your form which includes input named firstname, lastname, etc. ?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL-Injections, pls. also have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496

Comment: <html><head><title>mypage</title></head>
<body><form method="post" action="test.php">
<link type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h1>Sign up</h1> <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" /><label for="lastname">Last Name</label><input type="text" name="lastname" /> <br />Password :<input type="password" name="passowrd"> <br />Email-Id :<input type="email" name="email" /> <br /><input type="submit" value="SignUp" name="name" />
</form>
</body>
</html> @aycan yasit

Answer (score 0):

remove single quote from php variable

`$query = "INSERT INTO login_list (first_name, last_name, email,password) VALUES
 ($first_name, $last_name, $email,$password)";`

Answer (score 0):

if your data contain string that will put in "" or ''

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO login_list (first_name, last_name, email,password) VALUES 
     ('".$first_name."','".$last_name."', '".$email."','".$password."')";
```

i hope this will solve your problem if $_POST get correct data . you have to concat string at that time